# Find the recursive definition for the number of strings on 0, 1, 2 avoiding the substring 012?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

This is the question $a(n)$ the number of strings on $0, 1, 2$ avoiding the substring $012$ and the answer is $$a(n)=3a(n−1)−a(n−3)$$  with $$a(0)=1,a(1)=3,a(2)=9$$ My question is how to you get this recursive function? I have an exam on Thursday and I am struggling with the concept of finding the recursive definition for strings. Can someone explain how this works and give few examples to make it clear? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a string of length $n-1$, you can add any of $0$, $1$, or $2$ to the end of it to get a string of length $n$, so you get $3 a(n-1)$ strings. However, if the last two elements of the original string were $01$, then adding $2$ is not allowed. How many such strings are there? Well, they are found by noting that after removing the $01$ you have an arbitrary string of length $n-3$. So you must subtract $a(n-3)$ to avoid counting these.

More visually,
\begin{align*}
  \underbrace{...0}_{n-1} &\quad\Rightarrow\quad ...00,\ ...01,\ ...02 \\
  \underbrace{...1}_{n-1} &\quad\Rightarrow\quad ...10,\ ...11,\ ...12 \\
  \underbrace{...2}_{n-1} &\quad\Rightarrow\quad ...20,\ ...21,\ ...22
\end{align*}
so that every length $n-1$ string gives nine length $n$ strings. If the original string didn't contain $012$, neither will the new one, *except* for the last entry on the second row. If that length $n-1$ string ended in $01$, then we will have created a $012$ in the new string. But if that string ended in $01$, then the other digits in the string (there are $n-3$ of them) are arbitrary. So there are $a(n-3)$ ways in which we could have erroneously added the $012$. We must subtract that to get the right answer.

So for example $a(3) = 3a(2) - a(0) = 26$, $a(4) = 3a(3) - a(1) = 75$.

Answer (score -3):

$a_n=2a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$

$b_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}+a_{n-1}$

$c_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$

---

**Explanation:**

-First relation:

$2a_{n-1}$ indicates sequences starting by 1... or 2... while the relation $a$ is for unconstrained sequences

$b_{n-1}$ indicates 0... while $b$ is a sequence right-bounded by a $0$

-Second relation:

$c_{n-1}$ indicates 01... while $c$ is any sequence right-ended by $0...1$

$b_{n-1}$ indicates 00... while $a_{n-1}$ indicates 02...

-Third relation:

$a_{n-1}$ indicates 011... and $b_{n-1}$ points to 010...

---

**Example:n=3** (xxx)

Naive enumeration says $S=3*3*3-1=26$ where the subtracted case is 210

Recursive enumeration:

$a_3=2a_2+b_2=2(2a_1+b_1)+b_2=2(2(2a_0+b_0)+b_1)+b_2=8a_0+4b_0+2b_1+b_2$

$b_1=b_0+c_0+a_0=3$

$b_2=b_1+c_1+a_1$

$c_1=a_0+b_0=2$

$a_1=3$

$b_2=3+2+3=8$

$a_3=8+4+8+6=26$

---

**Example2:n=4** (xxxx)

-From informations above, $a_3=26,a_2=9,b_2=8,a_1=3,b_1=3$

$a_4=2a_3+b_3=2*26+b_3$

$b_3=b_2+c_2+a_2=8+c_2+9$

$c_2=b_1+a_1=3+3=6$

$b_3=23$

$a_4=52+23=75$ which matches previous results.

Comment: reason ??????????

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/573344)

Comment: @Nizar  ll clarify my intervention with examples  hold on, i thought it can be understood at first look

Comment: vtd + 2dvts because reviewers are failing to understand my approach, too bad, deplorably bad

Comment: I agree, the answer is indeed deplorably bad.

Comment: More explanation of the terms would be very helpful

Comment: @robjohn From what I understand, $a_n$ is the amount of valid strings of length $n$, $b_n$ is the amount of valid strings of length $n$ not beginning with $12$ (i.e. those that can follow a $0$), and $c_n$ is the amount of valid strings of length $n$ not beginning with $2$ (i.e. those that can follow a $01$).

Comment: @robjohn Equivalently, $a_n$ is the amount of valid strings of length $n$, $b_n$ is the amount of valid strings of length $n+1$ that begin with $0$, and $c_n$ is the amount of valid strings of length $n+2$ that begin with $01$.